# Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache2, php

After I've upgraded an Ubuntu server from 18.04 to 22.04 , i'm getting this error on a web site i'm hosting, just opening index.php
:

```
/var/www/my-site/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag',
 perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration,
```

This is the first 5 lines of my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options -Indexes

php_flag  display_errors        on
php_value error_reporting       2039
```

Either if I comment php_flag row, error persist.

What can I do ?